# adding products to best selling products list in Storefront home page

Tags: wordpress-theming, storefront

I might lose my mind, but I could not find out anywhere in wp-admin for adding a product to best selling product lists in Storefront theme's homepage.

Anyone guides me please?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thos are `best selling` products, to add them, you need to sell better :-).
I can think of 2 workarounds:

- You can create a coupon code for you, to make them free, and buy a lot of them so they will be included in the best selling products.
- You can use another widget and name it best selling products and include in it the products you want.

If this does not answer your needs, please provide more informations about your use case to find the best/better solution.

Cheers.

Comment: It's not the question how to sell better :) I just thought that there is a place that I can change the products in best-selling, recommendation, etc. parts in Storefront theme. However, it looks like that it's automated. For customising that, I will need to create my own homepage, not using their home template.

Thanks for answering anyway :)